Unable to access Ubuntu Pro graphical interface
I am having difficulties accessing the graphical user interface of Ubuntu Pro on my system. Despite several attempts, I have been unable to open the graphical Ubuntu Pro portal. Here are the details of my situation and the steps I have already taken:

System status:

My system is already linked to the Ubuntu Pro account "abc@xyz".
The services esm-apps, esm-infra, and livepatch are activated.


Attempted solutions:
a) Using the command sudo pro-client-gtk:

Error message: Command not found

b) Installing the ubuntu-advantage-tools package:

Already installed and up to date

c) Searching for "Ubuntu Pro" in system settings:

No corresponding entry found

d) Using the command sudo pro attach:

Output: "This machine is already attached to 'abc@xyz'"

e) Attempt to run sudo pro detach:

Aborted as it would deactivate the enabled services


Current situation:

I can only access the command-line output of pro status --all.
I am unable to open the graphical user interface that I can see on other PCs.



I would like to understand why I don't have access to the graphical interface and how I can solve this problem. Are there any further steps I should take, or could this possibly be a system-specific issue?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
